# Masonry is not working with jQuery initialise method using requirejs

Tags: jquery, requirejs, masonry

Masonry is not working when we are trying to initialise it with jQuery method. But it is working fine with vanilla javascript. jQuery is loaded in our master page and it is available globally. Am I missing something. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/418k4jm5/4/)

```
require(['https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js'],function(masonry){

$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 200
});

})
```

Comment: In your case, 'masonry' is being called as a method of $('.grid') (where is your jQuery require dependency, btw?) and the masonry object injected by requirejs is never called. Damon's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try. [Here is a link](http://masonry.desandro.com/extras.html) from the Masonry site to use require.

```
requirejs([
  'https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js',
], function(Masonry) {
    new Masonry('.grid', {

    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/418k4jm5/5/)